# How to return custom JSON from model?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a model with multiple fields but I only want to expose some or a combination of them. For example the model has `opening_time=12:00` and `closing_time=18:00` and I want to return the field `opening_hours=[12:00, 18:00]` to the JSON.

This is just an example, but I have also some other fields to combine into one in the return JSON. How can I do this? Is there a way to use a ModelSerializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read more abuot [`SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield).

You could do something like:

```
class StoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    opening_hours = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields = ('opening_hours', )

    def get_opening_hours(self, store_instance):
        opening_time = self.format_time(store_instance.opening_time)
        closing_time = self.format_time(store_instance.closing_time)
        return [opening_time, closing_time]

    def format_time(self, dt):
        return dt.strftime('%H:%M')
```

Comment: Thank you, It was just what I needed ! It's working now